# How to estimate (if/any) displacement/rotations between 2d line segments taken from 2 data sets

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, error-propagation

I am having set of pair of line segments (2D). Though each pair should be coincided on top of each other they are not so. I derive these two line sets using image based (e.g. CD) and manual method (e.g. AB). Now I know coordinates of end vertices i.e. vector data.

> So, Now I want to find is there any systematic displacements within my
>   extraction. Also, I want to give an overall figure for the accuracy of
>   image based method with respect to manually obtained line segments (My
>   idea is to find the displacement or any rotations are presented in
>   image data with respect to manual)

For that, I am not quite sure how would be my measure.. I mean should I use rmse or some other measures for this. (Actually, I can not imagine how rmse should be measured as my lines are not parallel and equidistant)

For you to get an idea, I should say that lengths and direction of corresponding pairs are not exactly same [see the figure]. (For the analysis, if you say, I need to get equidistant segments, then I can do it by projecting one on the other. I think, I should like this as I want to estimate displacements and rotations)

SO, I want your idea to estimate

any systematic errors of my extractions, in terms of displacement and rotations.

[image]
 any help please.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the distance between vertices as a metric, ie, AC+DE. It will be zero only if the two are coincident.

Comment: i could not get you. suppose lines are coincide but the starting and ending points are differ, then what happen? in my case, starting/ending of two line pair are not the same.